# Probability. Am I correct?

Tags: probability

Suppose that A and B are independent events such that $P(A) = 0.20$ and $P(B)=0.90$. Find $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$.

$P(A \cap B)=0.20\cdot0.90=0.18$

$P(A \cup B)=0.20+0.90-0.18=0.92$

Comment: Why do you think it could be not correct ?

Comment: P(A ∩ B)=0.20*0.10=0.18

These figures are not even related to the question, and the final equality is wrong.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I  wrote the wrong value in the question

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \cap B)=0.20\cdot0.10=0.18$

Yes, except $0.20\cdot 0.10$ is not equal to $0.18$.

$P(A \cup B)=0.20+0.90-0.18=0.92$

$0.90$ is wrong.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @Sam all good now.

Answer (score 0):

$ P ( A \lor B ) = P ( A \land B \lor A \land \lnot B \lor \lnot A \land B ) =  P ( A \lor \lnot A \land B ) = P(A) + (1- P(A))P(B)$ for the latter (the usual precedence for logical operators applies: $\lnot, \land, \lor$). In your case $0.2 + 0.8\cdot0.1$.

Comment: I have edited the question